# Some guidance with htaccess file setup

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've tried putting a .htaccess file in my project folder, I just wanted to test if it works for start, so I typed some junk in it, and hoped to get an Interntal Server Error, but I didn't.

I'm running my localhost with xampp, nothing too special.
I have my htaccess file placed at the root level, next to index.html

Any ideas to why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that apache is looking for `.htaccess`. Find your apache config, and look for the AccessFileName directive.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#accessfilename

The default is `.htaccess`, so this is probably OK.

2) Make sure that `AllowOverride` is not set to `none`.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

The default is `none`, but xampp might override - you'd have to check.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Both seem to be ok, 1) I have no AccessFileName at all in my config file, so im guessing its using the defualt of .htaccess. 2) It is set to all and not none. Any other ideas?